# using variable inside .env file for create react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

using variable inside .env file. In create react app.

I am trying to re use the env variable in other env variables, is this correct of way of doing, but i am not getting the value .

**.env**

```
A=hello
B=${A}/new
```

Comment: Could you try with `require('dotenv').config()` if you didn't ?

Comment: so i need to install dotenv package additionally and use it isn't

Comment: this is indeed a fun question... I honestly don't know if it is even possible, I've never seen this before. However, it's only a env file. Whenever you need to change some env variable, you'll need to change this file, so why don't just put `B=hello/new` ?

Comment: @AhmetZeybek create-react-app is already using `dotenv`

Comment: @DiogoLessa trying the impossible things is everyday's developer job thats how the requirement comes hahha :) and thats how people think of javascript

Comment: is this possible ?

Comment: @MoshFeu I don't know its deps, but if it has `dotenv`package he won't need to install package again, isn't it ? I'm experienced on NuxtJS & VueJS, these also have same problem with env variables. We can add custom envs with `require('dotenv').config()`, eventually both are JS frameworks

Comment: So this is not possible isn't even with dotenv package, i have ejected and check yes dotenv is pre installed in create react app

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS There's no harm in trying ?

Comment: sure will check and let you know

Comment: try with webpack .... see my [article](https://medium.com/@fyodorovandrei/simply-away-to-pass-environment-variables-into-react-js-app-with-webpack-bundler-5226af7ba60)

Answer (score 2):

**It's important to realize that env variables are only available in node environment and not in the browser.**

But if you're using `create-react-app`, It does some tricks for you and simulates the same behavior inside the browser, only if you put the `REACT_APP_` prefix before your env variables.

As the `create-react-app` docs says [here:](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

> Note: You must create custom environment variables beginning with
>   REACT_APP_. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to
>   avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could
>   have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require
>   you to restart the development server if it is running.

Comment: that i know but if i add the prefix with REACT_APP will it work ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS check this [doc](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#adding-development-environment-variables-in-env)

Comment: Yes. @DILEEPTHOMAS, when `create-react-app` includes your env files in your final bundle, it ignores the ones that don't have `REACT_APP_` prefix.